# JS - tab triggering another tab to run the code

Tags: javascript

I'm working on small automation and encountered one problem. At first attempt I wanted to send CORS request from one web to another but it is restricted on the domain I'm automating (redirect is not allowed). In this case I have to open the origin page first and then send the request. I'm gonna open new window `window.open` and send the request from there (Checked and it works). I'd like to make it as simple as possible so to do it I need to control the new tab from current tab - Force it to run some lines of code. Is it even possible in modern js ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be, you'd utilize something along the lines like:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
myWindow.document.write("<p>I replaced the current window.</p>");
```

Control gets finicky but this should help.

Comment: What about If I want to run xmlhttprequest code in the newly opened tab ?

Comment: You can append and add to the inner HTML. We call this XSS, you would implement <script> //your code here</script> and append it. Call it however you want.